# can i use a national schengen visa for study purpose in another schengen state?

Tags: schengen, study

i'm a Nigerian student studying in Istanbul, Turkey. I've been granted a one year national visa to Italy but i'm to enroll with the ERASMUS study program for a semester in Barcelona. Do i need to obtain a study schengen visa to proceed with my program or will the national visa suffice?

Comment: Will you be in Spain for more than 90 days? If you have plans to visit other Schengen countries, will all of your days in the Schengen area, not counting days in Italy, conform to the 90/180 rule?

Answer (score 1):

To stay for more than 90 days in Spain (+ all other Schengen countries excluding Italy) you need a study visa from Spain.

It is not clear what you have been granted the Italian visa for, but it is advised against using it for a completely different purpose than what you stated in your application. Studying in Barcelona instead of Italy would be such a case and it should be voided.